# Lead convert VR doesn't fire when account already exist

Tags: validation, lead-conversion

Hoping you all can help me out with this!

I have a Validation Rule that has a few required fields on the lead when converting to an opportunity. However, it becomes unnecessary when converting a lead and attaching it to an existing account.

Is there something I can add to the validation rule that would nullify the validation rule if 'Attach to Existing Account' is selected?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested the behavior of this field ConvertedAccountId? I would try to see if it has a value when you convert to an existing account. If you don't have any field in the lead object that you can use I am afraid your only option would be a trigger.